# Searching enum entries in groovy or java

Tags: java, search, groovy, enums

I have the following enum created in groovy:

```
enum Status {
    FAILED(0, "Failed"), 
    SUCCESSFUL(1, "Successful")

    private final int key
    private final String val
    public Status(int key, String val) {
        this.val = val
        this.key = key
    }
    String toString() { return val }
}
```

I would like to write a function to search the entries of my enum class that returns true of `Status.contains("Failed")`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Make sure your code sample is cleanly formatted for easy reading. Also specify what you want to do more clearly. Avoid using spoken-parlance words like 'wanna': it suggests sloppiness and disregard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy, you could do:

```
enum Status {
    FAILED(0, 'Failed'), 
    SUCCESSFUL(1, 'Successful')

    private final int key
    private final String val

    public Status(int key, String val) {
        this.val = val
        this.key = key
    }

    String toString() { val }

    static boolean containsVal(String val) {
        Status.values()*.val.contains val
    }
}

assert Status.containsVal('Failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write necessary methods yourself

Here is an example in java:

```
enum Status {
    FAILED(0, "Failed"),
    SUCCESSFUL(1, "Successful");

    private final int key;
    private final String val;

    Status(int key, String val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public static Status containsName(String name) {
        for (Status status : Status.values()) {
            if (status.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Status containsVal(String val) {
        for (Status status : Status.values()) {
            if (status.val.equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() { return val; }
}
```

Method `containsName` returns a Status instance if its name equals to an argument. Method `containsValue` returns a Status instance if its value equals to an argument.

```
Status failed = Status.containsName("FAILED");
Status successful = Status.containsVal("Successful");
```